# Issue with SQL query giving no results when including a variable in it

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code in my PHP file:

```
mysqli_set_charset($dbconexion,'utf8');
$usuario=$_POST ['usuario'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuariosinfo WHERE usuario=$usuario";
```

This gives me 0 results, even when I POST a valid "usuario" string. When I substitute the `usuario=$usuario` in the query with `usuario='valid-username'` it does show the desired results, but even if I substitute the `$usuario = "valid-username"` at the variable declaration, it wont work. I guess I'm missing something obvious but I seem unable to find what it is.

Comment: Explain your question more

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for  [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I'm alredy doing it Jay, I just wanted to quick test and faced this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put wrap the variable with apostrophes in the string.

```
$usuario=$_POST ['usuario'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuariosinfo WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
```

Remember that if at this point if the user adds a `'` in the input, the query will throw an error, since the symbol is not escaped.

So you can do this instead:

```
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconexion,$_POST ['usuario']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuariosinfo WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
```

This will prevent trouble in case the user inputs, for example,
`Jack Junior; drop table usuariosinfo;`

This will drop your table, you don't want that, right? So yea ;)

Comment: is there any way to PM you another doubt Phiter?, since it is really basic also and I will feel a little embarrased to post two of those the same day.

Comment: It seems I have not enough reputation... May I make the question and delete it after you answer it so it wont bother other users with more relevant questions?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing string delimiters.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuariosinfo WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
```

---

By the way, you should escape user inputs before passing them to sql queries. At least:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuariosinfo WHERE usuario = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $usuario) . "'";
```

Comment: Of course I am! because this will send string as opossed to my other programs that worked with numbers and do not need string delimiters. You solved it, thank you!